# Python + MongoDB: bulk/batch find query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB (PyMongo) collection of geo-locations specified by their longitude and latitude. Based on this I run distance-queries. Everything's perfectly fine.

**Scenario and Problem:** I have multiple GPS coordinates. For each of those coordinates I run a find operation for the collection of cites thus having a sequence of find-queries.

**Question:** But I wonder if there's a way to combine all those find-queries (for all GPS coordinate) into one bulk/batch-find operation sent to the MongoDB that retrieves all results at once? I know that there is a MongoDB BulkOperation, but this is used for write operations whereas items are found and updated or removed if found.

---

**What I got so far:** Here's my code. The structure of the MongoDB item is like this:

```
{'city': 'Berlin',
 'location': {'coordinates': [13.41053, 52.52437], 'type': 'Point'}}
```

Based on those items, I create a spherical index, that supports distance queries based on longitude and latitude:

```
db_collection.create_index([("location", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])
```

Now I can execute single find-queries that are giving me for instance other cities in a maximum distance around a point of interest. For instance this query gives me all cities (of my collection) that are in a distance of 30km around Berlin.

```
{'location': {'$nearSphere': {'$geometry': {'coordinates': [13.41053,
     52.524369999999998],
    'type': 'Point'},
   '$maxDistance': 30000}}}
```

That query is used in code like this:

```
max_distance = 30 #km
lng, lat = row['lng'], row['lat'] # Berlin
query = {"location": {"$nearSphere": { "$geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [lng, lat] }, "$maxDistance": max_distance * 1000} } }

#query = {"location": {"$nearSphere": {"$geometry": {"type": SON([("$coordinates", [row['lng'], row['lat']]), ("$maxDistance", 20000)])}}}}
#query = {"location": SON([("$nearSphere", [row['lng'], row['lat']]), ("$maxDistance", 500)])}
for doc in db_collection.find(query).limit(100):
    coords = doc['location']['coordinates']
    print (doc['city'], coords, haversine_distance_km(lng, lat, coords[0], coords[1]))
```

Which yield the correct result. **Remark:** The results contain the other cities only, but the distance between the query-location and city has to be calculated using the Harversine formular.

```
Berlin [13.41053, 52.52437] 0.0
Potsdam [13.06566, 52.39886] 27.215703627815788
```

---

PS: the original list of locations (for testing purposes) is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{'city':"Berlin", 'lat':52.5243700, 'lng':13.4105300},
                   {'city':"Potsdam", 'lat':52.3988600, 'lng':13.0656600},
                   {'city':"Hamburg", 'lat':53.5753200, 'lng':10.0153400}]);
df
```

Comment: So you are looking to run the query for multiple cities at a time? It seems a bit ugly to me, but the first thing that came to mind was to dynamically build the query using the $or operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/ . I think you could $or together coordinates. Problem would be if you do that, you won't know which cities are close to which other city, it would just spit them all out.

Comment: Yeah kind of. I was thinking about $in but this does not work with the geoSphere. Same is true for the type=MultiPoint instead of Point. But as you said, then you wouldn't know the pairs of cities with the distances. No solution yet.

Comment: I haven't done it with Mongo, but if speed is really necessary for your application you could consider multithreading. The thing is, I am not sure how Mongo handles multiple read operations simultaneously, so it might do them concurrently, or just queue the requests up which wouldn't be helpful to you. Just throwing the idea out there in case it might spark an idea.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter much in the end since the request are generated in a Spark environment and therefore each chunk of data processing is generating a sequence of requests. The database will be a distributed MongoDB with load balancing and I guess it can handle concurrent requests. It's a different thing with a local MongoDB singleton instance.